# LINQ and ExcelQueryFactory

Tags: c#, excel, linq

I have problems to select all rows out of a special worksheet which has no data entry in the first cell.

I am using ExcelQueryFactory to retrieve the data.

Here is my code until now...

```js
// get the worksheets out of the source file 
var sourceFactory = new ExcelQueryFactory(fullFileName);
            
// we search by regex function for (##)
var regexSearchTerm = new Regex(@"\(d+)");

// get a list of worksheets whose have a number in it's name
var worksheets = (from sheets in sourceFactory.GetWorksheetNames() 
                  where regexSearchTerm.Matches(sheets).Count > 0 
                  select sheets).ToList();

// determine all the rows which has an item in the first cell
foreach (var wsheetItem in worksheets)
{
  var affectedRows = < the linq query I am searching for >
}
```

The problem now is that I don't get a valid linq statement to select the rows where the first cell in a row is empty.

I hope someone can help me out...

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To select all the rows that have first cell empty, you can use the following code:

```
IEnumerable<Row> affectedRows =
      from row in wsheetItem.Descendants<Row>()
      where (row.Descendants<Cell>().First().CellValue == null)
      select row;
```